# Google Sign In in iOS with server

Tags: ios, oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm adding Google Sign In to my iOS app. In [the guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) the told you to create an iOS Oauth id but, in the [Android guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), they also told that if you authenticate with a backend server you need to use the Web Oauth id instead of the Android one.

So my question is, if I'm using a server in my iOS app, do I need to use the Web Oauth id or the iOS one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** I'm using a server in my iOS app, do I need to use the `Web Oauth id` or the iOS one?

> You have to use iOS Oauth id for Google Sign In because From iOS End without valid iOS `Oauth id` you can not use Google SDK`. Also,`bundle identifier`came into picture if you are talking about`Sign In` with Google by using iOS App.

**In one word you can't use Web Oauth id in iOS App.**

**Update:**

iOS, Android and Server is totaly different because for iOS we have to add .plist file, For Android .json file into project and so on.

You have to intilise Google SDK By using client ID as below.

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = Client_ID
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Hitesh. But if I have the app also for Android, will this one use the Web Oauth? Also, at the server part, should they add all of the client ids (web and ios)?

Comment: iOS, Android and Server is totaly different because for iOS we have to add .plist file, For Android .Json file.

Comment: Yeah but do you know what client id should be used in that case?

Comment: You have to intilise Google SDK by using client ID like         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "Client_ID"